# How to fully style UISearchbar using Pixate?

Tags: ios, pixate

Pixate seems to be unable to style UISearchBar's UITextField. Neither the text, corner radius etc. is styled, no matter how broadly I select `text-field`.

Also, there is an annoying dark hairline at the top and bottom of the UISearchBar as soon as I try to style it (e.g. give it a background color) using Pixate.
Furthermore, the cancel button label suddenly has white text and I found no way to overwrite it to any other color.

So the question is: Am I missing something or does Pixate in fact not support this (yet)?

#### What I want it to look like:

[image: What I want it to look like]

#### What it looks like using Pixate.

[image: What it looks like using Pixate]

#### The stylesheet:

```
table-view {
  separator-style: single-line;
  separator-color: #eeeeee;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

table-view-cell {
  background-color: white;
}

search-bar {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Treat it like you would a normal CSS selector.

```
search-bar button {
    color: white;
}
```